# Convert A Union Query To LINQ To Entity Query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Can someone help me with converting this query to a Linq to entities query in the proper way. I am fairly new to Linq and want to write these queries properly. This is a fairly involved one for what im doing with UNION and sub queries in it

```
SELECT pf.FileID, pf.ServerName, pf.MigrationType 
FROM pOrders pf 
WHERE pf.FileID IN (select GCMFileID FROM Signals
                    where SignalFileID = " + FileID + ")
UNION 
SELECT pf.FileID, pf.ServerName, pf.MigrationType
FROM pOrders pf 
WHERE pf.FileID = " + FileID + "
order by pf.MigrationType desc
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It's not all THAT hard.  Linq has select clauses, where clauses, orderbys, unions, etc.   It's practically a straight port.

Comment: This query is begging to be injected. With attacks.

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, I saw comments... but

```
var signalIds = Signals.Where(s => s.SignalFileId = FILEID).Select(x => x.GCMFileID ).ToArray();

pOrders.Where(pf => signalIds.Contains(pf.FileID))
.Union(
pOrders.Where(pf => pf.FileID == FILEID))
.OrderByDescending(u => u.MigrationType)
.Select(u => new {u.FileID, u.ServerName, u.MigrationType});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var innerquery = from t in db.Signals
                 where t.SignalFileID == FileID
                 select new {t.SignalFieldID};
var query = (from p in db.pOrders
            where p.FieldID.Contains(innerquery.SignalFieldID)
            select new {p.FileID, p.ServerName, p.MigrationType}).Union
            (from p in db.pOrders
            where p.FieldID ==FieldID
            orderby p.MigrationType
            select new {p.FileID, p.ServerName, p.MigrationType})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help habib. where p.FieldID.Contains(innerquery.SignalFieldID) Is having a problem because there is no access to the property SignalFieldID from innerquery

Comment: Ok I got it this far long l = long.Parse(innerquery.FirstOrDefault().GCMFileID.ToString()); Then in the where clause..where p.FileID.Contains(l.ToString())   I am getting a compilation error stating long does not contain a definition for Contains

Comment: p.FileID.Contains(l.ToString()) here just do  p.FileID.Contains(l)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I thought I'd add my two cents hoping I can save some time for someone who thinks as I originally did that Union() is the correct method to use.

My first misstep was to create a custom comparer with my entity's logical keys after I hit my first error that the xml column type cannot be used in a distinct. Then, Linq to Entities complained it did not recognize Union(). I notice the accepted answer calls ToArray. This brings the entire results of the first query into memory before doing the Union. The OP wants Linq to Entities so you need to act on an IQueryable. Use Concat. The entire query will run in the database.

```
var innerquery = (from t in db.Signals
             where t.SignalFileID == FileID
             select t.SignalFileID);
var query = (from p in db.pOrders
        where innerquery.Contains(p.FileID)
        select new {p.FileID, p.ServerName, p.MigrationType})
    .Concat(from p in db.pOrders
        where p.FileID == FileID
        select new {p.FileID, p.ServerName, p.MigrationType})
    .OrderBy(o => o.MigrationType);
```